# Secure Token Service using SSO with ADFS2 OR username/password?

Tags: security, asp.net-mvc-4, single-sign-on, token, ws-federation

I currently have a MVC4 home-grown secure token service (STS) that communicates with our own authentication database.  All is working just fine with this setup.  As a new feature I need to add the ability for single sign on (SSO) through ADFS2 for those users that are on the domain (bypasses the current un/pw screen, and they're just 'in').  To be clear there really are 3 different login possibilities that need to be handled:  domain user (SSO), domain credentials (domain user not on domain entering their domain un/pw), and the original un/pw auth from database.  Knowing what I know about adding web.config settings to the relying application to wire up the STS, how would I wire up both wsFederation passive redirect options (current redirect to STS for un/pw, and the ADFS option)?  Is this something that would have to be handled in code, through an overloaded class such as WSFederationAuthenticationModule?  What would be the best way to handle what I want?  Any code examples?  Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 1):

You just have your login screen on your custom STS and two additional buttons, "login with ADFS" or "login as domain user". Both buttons are redirects to two other STSes your STS is federated with (your STS plays then role of either an Identity Providing STS or a Relying STS).

That is not very complicated. What you need is to create two `SignInRequestMessage`s and using their `WriteQueryString` build two urls to two different STSes. Another way would be to use the `WSFederationAuthenticationModule::CreateSignInRequest` method.

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.signinrequestmessage(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.signinrequestmessage%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

[http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.wsfederationauthenticationmodule.createsigninrequest(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.identitymodel.services.wsfederationauthenticationmodule.createsigninrequest%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Consuming responses is tricker as you need a single uri (or two different uris) that play an endpoint roles. In the uri you need a token receiver and try to create a token out of the SAML sent by the provider.

If you peek at the source of a community replacement of the `wif:FederatedPassiveSignIn` method I wrote once, you will get the idea

http://code.google.com/p/net45federatedpassivesignin/source/browse/trunk/+net45federatedpassivesignin+--username+wzychla@gmail.com/Community.IdentityModel.Web/Controls/CommunityFederatedPassiveSignIn.cs?spec=svn6&r=6

(at least half of the code is responsible for the WebForms user control infrastructure but the other half is what you are looking for)

Unfortunately also, such custom mixed scenario is not easily handled with just the configuration of federation modules.

Comment: Thanks so much for your assistance.  I'm trying to have one STS handle all the workload, so let me run this past you to see if I'm in the ballpark: Within my relying app I currently have a <federationConfiguration> element in the web config. This tells the RA where to go for authentication, and then where to return.  How can I dynamically build this section so I can theoretically apply a single STS to any website?  Is there more involved here than I'm thinking?

Comment: No, you get it wrong. The RA still goes to a **single** STS. But then, the STS can act as an identity provider STS (so it goes back) or a relying STS (so it redirects further, to another STS). From the application perspective, there is a **single** identity provider, the mentioned STS. Whether or not it authenticates users directly or asks another STS for help, it doesn't matter from the RP perspective as it still gets claims from the same source, signed with same certificate. What I described then is how to have an R-STS that possibly points to multiple Idp-STSes or authenticates directly.

Comment: Ok.  Current thought:  My app that requires ADFS is accessed through a link on a web page that has many links to different apps.  This link will point to a website that will dynamically create the redirect URL that points to the correct STS, realm url, and the timestamp.  This way the current web app & sts can continue to do what it's doing, and the other auth process can access what it needs (adfs sts).  Does this sound like it could be successful?  It might be more complicated than the R-STS idea, but I understand how this will work far better.  Thanks for your help.

Comment: Chances are this could work, however it sounds weird to control the login flow of an application from another application. Noone does it this way. Why are you so much against the idea of a r-sts?

Comment: I'm thinking about a method that might work and that I understand how it works.  Sure, I understand the concept of what's happening and my current implementation works fine I don't believe I understand all the actual processes.  Take this and create a STS that dynamically determines can talks with multiple STSs? There is where I'm mostly lost.

Comment: Talking to another STS is just redirecting and consuming back the response. If you do this for RP - STS then doing this for RP - R-STS - Idp-STS is just the same. Are you lost at the conceptual level or at the technical level?

Comment: I appreciate you not giving up on me.  One problem is that I don't have a working ADFS STS yet, so that needs to get completed.   Within the R-STS I believe I need to determine where I need to go (ADFS will always be tried initially) and dynamically create the SignInRequestMessage (then used in ProcessSignInRequest, then in ProcessSignInResponse). This SignInRequestMessage can point to the ADFS STS and having a realm of the original realm url.  It should route back just fine.  Am I on track here?

Comment: Yes. I am not sure however if this is you to determine that. Rather, I would give the choice to the user. A login screen with few links to different idp-stses in your r-sts (login with adfs, login with adfs2, login with yet another sts) as well as the possibility to directly provide the login and password.

Comment: While I still don't have my ADFS login working (waiting on a cert), I'm trying to figure out how the R-STS will work.  Up until now, all my wiring has been straight-forward: basically change your web.config and everything is wired up (simplified, obviously).    Does my R-STS need to have the wiring that my client app has (system.identityModel.services) that points to a STS?  Any way I can contact you directly?

Comment: Yes, contact me directly.

Comment: Sent email, please let me know you received it.